# Why multiple monomorphic caches are created instead of one polymorphic

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm reading [this article](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html) on monomorphism and there's the following code snippet there:

```
function ff(b, o) {
  if (b) {
    return o.x
  } else {
    return o.x
  }
}

ff(true, { x: 1 })
ff(false, { x: 2, y: 0 })
ff(true, { x: 1 })
ff(false, { x: 2, y: 0 })
```

> How many property access inline caches are in the function ff? What’s
>   state they are in? 
>   Answers: there are 2 caches, both are monomorphic because each sees only objects of one shape.

I thought there would be one polymorphic because earlier the author shows:

```
f({ x: 4, y: 1 }) // polymorphic, degree 2
f({ x: 5, z: 1 }) // polymorphic, degree 3
f({ x: 6, a: 1 }) // polymorphic, degree 4
f({ x: 7, b: 1 }) // megamorphic
```

The function is passed objects of different structure and they mutate monomorphic cache into polymorhpic. Why is different with the example in question?

Comment: I would say that the author is somewhat confused, as the `ff` function does the same thing regardless of what the first argument is, but seeing as I haven't read the entire article, and know that the author works for Google and used to be part of the V8 team, he probably knows what he's doing?

Comment: @adeneo, yeah, I assume he is. I just want to understand the topic)

Comment: Oh, it's just an example to show that the `o.x` lookup is cached from the first call to the function etc.

Comment: Right, but *each* `o.x` lookup has its own cache.

Comment: @Pointy - sure, it looks the same, and returns the same, but it's two different lookups for the interpreter.

Comment: Yes right. As the article goes on it becomes clearer that the IC concept applies to just about every operation in every expression.

Comment: The shapes would be clearer I think if one swapped the function calls a little, as it's easier to see that each `return x.o` only sees the same thing -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2c4sdu2b/

Comment: As a sidenote, [Vyacheslav](http://stackoverflow.com/users/662844/vyacheslav-egorov) *(the author)* was here just yesterday ?

Comment: I am a little surprised that the V8 compiler wouldn't simply optimize this to make the function always return `o.x`. Google could learn a lot from Roslyn.

Comment: @TravisJ - true, you'd think it would be easy to optimize it when an `if..else` condition has the exact same code in both cases, but maybe there are unintended consequences to do so, that isn't immediately clear ?

Comment: @adeneo - Based on the lookup explained here, there does seem to be a difference in that each property access gets its own cache. However, given that property access should be looking at a hash table, which has an O(1) lookup, why even go through the work to iterate at that point? Perhaps I am missing something there, but this doesn't seem to be how other compilers work with regards to property access.

Comment: @TravisJ the hash table lookup is exactly the "expensive" thing that the runtime is trying to avoid, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Pointy - Why would O(1) be expensive though? What makes that aspect the "expensive" call? Is it related to the idea that using a hash lookup requires the object to be in megamorphic mode (also called Dictionary mode I think)? What did the structure of the properties look like prior to that (monomorphic) that they were able to be iterated but not accessed directly by name? Any idea?

Comment: @TravisJ O(1) just means that it's constant time (in terms of the size of the hash table). The *size* of the constant is relatively large; for example, the runtime has to compute the hash code of the property name. The IC as described strikes me as something designed to be much less expensive than that (though I confess to not understanding how the "shape" is computed efficiently).

Comment: @TravisJ consider that it might not be `o.x` - it might be `o.iOftenProgramInJava`.

Comment: @Pointy - Considering that there can be no collisions with regards to the hash (in other words, there is only one property name per record in the hash) there shouldn't need to be a hash code computation for properties in JavaScript.

Comment: @TravisJ well by definition a "hash table" has to involve a hash code; otherwise it's not a hash table. I'm not sure what you're thinking, but to me the lookup, though constant time, has to determine a position in the table to look and then perform a O(n) (in terms of the property name length) name comparison.

Comment: @Pointy - Well, it is termed a "hash table" so that is the reference I also went with, although it seems more like a dictionary, where the key is simply the string representation of the property name (hence no real hash computation since you could just use .ToString()). Performing a lookup in O(n) time for a property name guaranteed to be unique seems excessive though, don't you think?

Comment: @TravisJ how would you determine whether a property name used in a reference is the same as an actual property name without doing at least a Boyer-Moore style string comparison (which, worst case, is still linear)? Also, you really can't have a hash table without a hash code; it just doesn't make sense. You can have other types of sub-linear lookup tables (Trie tree for example), but a hash table by it's basic nature involves a hash code.

Comment: @Pointy - (I hope this isn't too drawn out, I think it is an interesting topic). The Boyer-Moore style, which seems to me is a sliding window, would be good for multiple matches and collisions. However, given that the key is guaranteed to be unique, and therefore either exists or does not exist in its full form, wouldn't looking to see if the key exists in the single form of the entire name suffice?

Comment: @TravisJ yes, but think about how you compare one name to another. It's not a constant-time operation. CPUs don't do constant-time string comparisons. (And of course in general most objects have multiple properties.)

Comment: @Pointy - Hm, yes I see your point with regards to constant-time string comparisons now. Wouldn't comparing the value of the argument in the call, to the value stored in the cache, require the same comparison though?

Comment: @TravisJ yes that's the thing I don't understand; how does this "shape" determination take place? Maybe it's some sort of hash on the overall object structure? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @Pointy, _how does this "shape" determination take place_ - that was going to be my next question) But I guess getting the answer for this one might not be easy unless `Vyacheslav` sees it. How would you go about understanding this topic?

Comment: @Maximus you can just ask questions in the comments to the blog post or by mail - answer guaranteed :) Shape computation is discussed in my much older blog post http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov, thanks for noticing the question! Great articles by the way. And talks. I'm watching Benchmarking JavaScript now. It's like the new world out there. How can I obtain your email? :)

Comment: @Maximus my email is on the front page of mrale.ph :) (it's me (at) mrale.ph )

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov, yeah, got it, thanks) Also found you on FB

Comment: @Maximus I recommend using mail to reach me - I limit my Facebook contacts to people I know personally.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov, np, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "inline cache" things exist at each distinct property reference in the code. Thus in the function:

```
function ff(b, o) {
  if (b) {
    return o.x   // IC here
  } else {
    return o.x   // IC here
  }
}
```

Those two `return` statements each have their very own inline cache. Because of the way the function is invoked in the example, the first `return` only happens with objects of the first shape, and the second only happens with objects of the second shape. Thus, each cache (after those four calls to `ff()`) will have only seen 1 shape.

After a *fifth* call to the function like this:

```
ff(true, { x: 1, z: 10 });
```

that first IC would have seen *two* shapes, so its IC would then be polymorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Every property access `o.x` has its own IC, even if the same property of the same object is accessed multiple times.

If you run `node --trace-ic someScript.js`, you can see to which line number the ICs belong to.